Why is my chrome test not opening quickly?
I have created a maven project and when I run the application, Chrome does not open quickly but Edge does. I am using Selenium + Java 4.20.0.
Though there's no error, I could see this on my console:
May 10, 2024 1:31:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.manager.SeleniumManager lambda$runCommand$1
WARNING: There was an error managing chromedriver (error decoding response body); using driver found in the cache


Can you add more details, how you load the webdriver, which version youre using etc.

Also, to add to Dimitar's comment. The underlying arch, if its x86, arm64, etc.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Does the machine that you are running the code on have an active internet connection? Does it has a good, consistent internet connection? SeleniumManager is Selenium's version of a built-in DriverManager and it looks at the Chrome version installed and then checks for the equivalent chromedriver version. If it doesn't exist, it downloads it. It sounds like something is going wrong in that process and that's likely what's making Chrome take longer than Edge. When it doesn't succeed, Selenium falls back to using a driver found in the cache.
Assuming you have a stable internet connection on that machine, I would suggest that you delete all driver instances on that machine and then run the script again. Selenium should download the driver again. That might be slightly slower the first time but once it has the driver, it should be fast from then on.
